# SpriteKit screen width not measuring properly

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I have this Sprite Kit game that passes some balls across the screen and the user has to tap them. If the user misses a ball and it goes off the screen then they lose.

The game works perfect when testing it on my iPhone but when I run it on my iPad it doesn't work as it's supposed to. It also doesn't work on iPhone X simulator. When the game first starts up it goes to the Start Scene, but when the user clicks "Start Game" it goes to the Game Scene and then automatically cuts to the game over scene without spawning any balls. After I hit "Play again" it will spawn the balls as it should but the measurements of detecting if the balls are out of bounds are not correct (which they are when testing on my iPhone 8 Plus).

Here are the areas where I think the problem may be coming. This is where the widths for things come from.

EnumerateChildNodes function to remove the balls once of the scene:

```
func searchChildNodes() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") { (node: SKNode, nil) in
        if node.position.x < -25 || node.position.x > self.size.width + 25 {
            print("balls Out")
            node.removeFromParent()
            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            self.gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene")
            self.gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            self.view?.presentScene(self.gameScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically in the `if statement`:

```
if node.position.x < -25 || node.position.x > self.size.width + 25
```

If remove the part after the `||` operator then the game lets the balls do what they are supposed, only without detecting if the are out of bounds on the right side of the screen.

**Update**

Here is the code that sets the position of the balls when they are spawned:

```
if ballDirection == "right" {
    player?.position.x = 0
    moveRight()
}
else {
    player?.position.x = (self.scene!.frame.size.height)
    moveLeft()
}
```

Comment: From what I am seeing, you are mixing `view.frame` and `scene.frame`, never use the `view.frame`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Changing that did not fix the problem

Comment: Then your issues are not in the code provided.  There are too many things going on that are outside of the default behavior, like your anchor point being (0,0) and not (0.5,0.5).  Create an example with as few code as possible that replicates your issue.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon should my anchor point be (0.5,0.5)? I have it set to 0,0. Not entirely sure where the problem lies though... When I run the game on iPad or iPhone X it has this problem.

Comment: It is whatever you want it to be,  0.5,0.5 makes it easier because that means (0.0) is the center of your screen

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I narrowed it down to the if statement and updated to post.

Comment: That’s not going to help you, we clearly know that node is going into that if statement, the question becomes why?  When you create a ball, it is outside of that range, but we have no idea on how that can happen because the code wasn’t provided.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok so I added the part that determines the position the balls spawn from based on what direction they are going. Let me know If that's not. I'm just starting out with this so I don't have my head completely rapped around it.

Comment: You are using height not width on x